# How to access and modify array inside class?

Tags: php, class

I'm having problems with an array inside a class. I can access it if I set it to static but I cannot figure out how to modify it and access it on my function if it's not static.

```
class Example {
    protected static $_arr = array(
        "count",
    );

    public static function run($tree) {
        $_arr[] = "new";
        print_r($_arr );
    }
}
```

How do I access the array, modify it and print it from inside my public function "run"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_arr[] = "new";`

refers to an array that will be local to your function. to access a static variable of your class, you have to use the syntax ==> `self::staticVariableName`

you code should be :

```
class Example {
protected static $_arr = array(
    "count",
);

public static function run($tree) {
    self::$_arr[] = "new";
    print_r(self::$_arr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a snippet from the code of @MQuirion . Here I wrote how to handle non-static properties in your class. I hope now you can work with your array inside your class.

```
class Example {
    protected $_arr = array(
        "count",
    );

    public function run($tree) {
        // print new array + your properties
        $this -> _arr[] = $tree;
        //To print only new assigned values without your declared properties
        $this -> _arr = $tree;
        print_r($this->_arr );
    }
}
$obj = new Example();
$tree = array('a','b','c');
$result = $obj->run($tree);
```